# Can I be banned from AdMob for seeing real ads (impressions)?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads, impressions

Question 1:
I know that clicking on real ads in my own app can get me banned but does that include impressions ?
I developed app and tested ads with test ads but now I want to see how it looks with real ads (which ads appear ....). How can I test that if I can be banned for that ?

Question 2:
Does AdMob gets data on how many ads were seen because I implemented code that sends event to Firebase Analytics each time ad is shown to user? Do I need it (should I delete that part of code)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, Admob collects how many users have seen the add and how many times and clicks too and this is how they decide `CPM` which is `cost per thousand impression` and `CPC` which is `cost per click`. `CPC` and `CPM` are essential to evaluate your earnings through ads.

1. As far as first question is concern regarding clicking your ads, you can test your beta releases [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180?hl=en-IN) and [here too](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). However they don't ban immediately as one can click real ads mistakenly but repeated such event can cause a ban.
2. Answering your seccond question if you just want how many users have seen the ad, Admob can give you that metrics.

Comment: first question was will I be banned for impressions of real ads on my own app ? thank you

Comment: as I said " they don't ban immediately as one can click real ads mistakenly but repeated such event can cause a ban." Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I can answer first question. Impression on your own app does not ban you, I always install my own app after it is live in play to see if real ads are showing or not, but don't click on them. Also do not encourage any friends to click on them on their mobile. Google knows everything!

Comment: can i avoid ban by adding test device when requesting ad ?:
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") 
                .build();

Comment: Yes, u can add.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you will press to the ad one or two times you will not be banned. But it really not needed, cos' you can use test-ads; they have got the same lifecycle.
2. Inside admob it is possible to see total amount of shown/clicked ads and how much money you have earned. Imo, in most cases you need not to write such statistic.

Comment: I used test ads in beggining but now when I registered ad unit I saw option for ad Frequency (how many impressions in minute) and I dont know how to test that without having real ads because creating that ad unit gives real ads ?